# Route all traffic from port over non default route

Tags: iptables, routing, synology

All my traffic goes through a subscription VPN service via a gateway. I now want to have a Site-to-Site OpenVPN connection between two synology NAS, with one sitting behind the VPN gateway, the other off-site.

I made a simplified sketch of my Setup:

[image: Sketch]

The default route of the NAS should be `192.168.100.1` (VPN Gateway), but this breaks the functionality of the OpenVPN server running on `192.168.10.20`, it can be reached, but the out going traffic is apparently routed over the VPN-Gateway.

Is there a way to add some rule that will route all traffic out going from `192.168.10.20:1194` through `192.168.10.1`?

The NAS is from Synology, so I can set new iptable rules or ip routes, but my general experience with Synology is to only make minimally invasive change to the config or stuff will break.

**Edit 18.07.2022:**

Based on [@Tom Yan](https://serverfault.com/users/569990/tom-yan) and https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/Zwei_Default_Gateways_in_einem_System (german) I came up with this on boot script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "1 gateway-table" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.10.20 table gateway-table
ip route add default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth1 table gateway-table
ip rule add from 192.168.10.20/32 table gateway-table
ip rule add to 192.168.10.20/32 table gateway-table

exit 0
```

Unfortnatly this isn't working either.

Comment: Check out `ip rule`.

Comment: @TomYan I tried your hint, but didn't get it working, what am I missing?

Comment: Instead of `from 192.168.10.20/32`, I'd probably try `iif lo ipproto udp sport 1194` (or omit `ipproto udp` if your server does both). I can't tell for sure if it'd still be affected by "multihome issue" though. Check out the `multihome` option of OpenVPN maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Tom Yan](https://serverfault.com/users/569990/tom-yan) suggested adding `multihome` to the server config worked!

The Synology OpenVPN server config can be edit with:

```
sudo vi /usr/syno/etc/packages/VPNCenter/openvpn/openvpn.conf
```

just add `multihome` to the end of the file and reboot the device. Afterwards you can set different interfaces for the default gateway and the listing interface of the OpenVPN server.

There is no need for any additional routes or rules.

Comment: To make your answer valid you may want to correct the typo in the keyword. It's `multihome`, not `mutlihome`.